# MYSQL error when using foreign Key which references to a PK in the same Table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a problem with a foreign Key. In this case the FK references a PK within the same table. This is the SQL code for creating it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE NODOS(

    tax_id                      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    parent_tax_id               INTEGER,
    rank                       VARCHAR(50),
    division_id                 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    gencode_id             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    mitochondrial_genetic_code_id              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    comments                    VARCHAR(250),
    embl_code                   VARCHAR(5),
    inherited_div_flag          INTEGER,
    inherited_GC_flag           INTEGER,
    hidden_subtree_root_flag    INTEGER,
    GenBank_hidden_flag         INTEGER,
    inherited_MGC_flag          INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY(tax_id),
    CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY(division_id) REFERENCES divisiones(division_id),
    CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY(gencode_id) REFERENCES GENCODES(gencode_id),
    CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY (mitochondrial_genetic_code_id) REFERENCES GENCODES(gencode_id),
    CONSTRAINT  FOREIGN KEY (parent_tax_id) REFERENCES NODOS(tax_id));
```

When running the code in MySQL it comes up the following error:

> `` Database - ERROR - Mysql query error  1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user`.`nodos`, CONSTRAINT `nodos_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_tax_id`) REFERENCES `nodos` (`tax_id`)) ``

Why does it happen if there is no null in any of the columns?

Comment: so first enter NODOS  tax id row parent_tax:id  and then insert the the row

Answer (score 1):

You would better understand the reason with the following example. Foreign key relation is like child and parent relationship. You cannot have a child without a parent in real life so its the same implementation here.

You cannot create a child before parent because child would be referring to something that doesn't exists.

Correct Order of table creation is Parent/referenced tables in your query divisiones, GENCODES tables first etc. and this remains true for loading data as well. Data has to be loaded in parent tables then when you load data in child table would know what to refer the data from. I guess you are loading data in child before having relevant data in parent.

```
mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TABLE parent (
    ->     id INT NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TABLE child (
    ->     id INT,
    ->     parent_id INT,
    ->     INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    ->         REFERENCES parent(id)
    ->         ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

We create tables with foreign keys by creating child before parent tables like below similar way data loading has to be done in parent first followed by child.

```
mysql> drop table child;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop table parent;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE child (
    ->     id INT,
    ->     parent_id INT,
    ->     INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    ->         REFERENCES parent(id)
    ->         ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB;
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: If you want to retract your answer, please simply delete it. Vandalism will be rolled back by site policy.